# CakePHP this->paginate not using order field

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

No matter what I do I can't get it to respect the order I specify.

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'Car' => array(
        'limit' => 6,
        'order' => array(
            'Car.year' => 'desc'
        ),
        'table' => 'cars'
    )
);
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT `Car`.`id`, ... `Car`.`year`,... FROM `cars` AS `Car` WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 6
```

Comment: I've tried specifying it at the top of the controller using `var $paginate` and also taking it outside the 'Car' => array

No matter what I do I can't get it to order. Other models are ordering fine for me though :S Please help!

Comment: why are you definying the table? IMO uncessary. also try to flatten the array (no Car with subarray, just "limit", "order", ...)

Comment: Thanks Mark, to be honest I'm just trying everything I can think of. Taking those things out doesn't fix the problem either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I was using a :sort in my url parameters. Once I took that out all was well :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one item, you don't need/shouldn't use an array:

```
//one thing
var $order = "Model.field DESC";

//multiple things
var $order = array("Model.field" => "asc", "Model.field2" => "DESC");
```

([per this page](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1064/order))

Comment: I tried this too but it didn't work. Should this be specified at the top of the controller?

Comment: no, yours should work. but you still didnt show us the crucial part about how you actually retrieve data. there might be your mistake.

Comment: @KieranYo - Even if this doesn't fix your problem I would keep it as a non-array, then continue looking further.  I've had a similar problem many many times, and I always fix it by removing the array.

Comment: @mark all I'm doing after that is a $result = $this->paginate(); or $result = $this->paginate('Cars'); both with the same results.

Comment: @KieranYo - I believe it should be singular:  $this->Paginate('Car');

Answer (score 0):

Note too that virtual fields are ignored by default when paginating.

See "Control which fields used for ordering" in [Cake 2.0 Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) documentation.

Example:

```
$this->MyModel->virtualFields['count'] = 0;
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'fields' => 'COUNT(id) AS MyModel__count',
        'group' => ('MyModel.group_id'),
        'order' => array('MyModel__count' => 'DESC'),
    );
// IMPORTANT: pass sortable fields including the virtual field as 3rd parameter:
$log = $this->Paginator->paginate('MyModel', null, array('MyModel__count', 'id'));
```